# Initializing a const object with a function that may throw c++

Tags: c++, exception

I am writing a function that invokes a function that may throw in order to initialize a const member.  The problem is: if I put the initialization inside the try block, it gets deleted when it goes out of scope.  If I put the initialization outside the try block, I can't catch the exception.  A way around it would be:

```
double functionA()
{
  double a;
  try
  {
    a=functionThatMayThrow();
  }
  catch(std::except&p)
  {
    std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error(__func__);
  }
  const double b=a;
  //More code that uses b and computes x
  return x; 
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this.  Something like:

```
double functionA()
{
  const double b=functionThatMayThrow();
  //catch the exception somehow and rethrow with nested information

  //Unchanged
  //More code that uses b and computes x
  return x; 
}
```

Perhaps I am just taking a completely wrong approach to the problem.  Could you give me any suggestions please? Any boost or c++11 related solution is also good.

Comment: You can `try{ const double b = mayThrow(); // more code that uses b and computes x; return x; } catch( std::exception &p ) ...`, but why must `b` be `const`?

Comment: you could not bother catching the exception in the function and let an outer `catch()` block deal with it. After all if the variable does not get set can the function proceed anyway?

Comment: do you want to build a stack trace by adding the function's name to any passing exception, is that it?

Comment: @cicto: I see.  I find your solution good (I feel so dumb right now).  The const b requirement would be mostly for const-correctness.

Comment: @Galik: I want to build a stack traceback

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: yes, that is precisely what I am trying to do.  Do you know if there is a better way of doing that?

Comment: @KahnYe: Assuming you have valid reasons for doing this, a simple direct way is to put all of the function body in a `try` clause. It doesn't matter where the exception originated, if it escapes out of the `try` clause you `catch` it and add function name. You can even centralize that logic in a function that takes a lambda and a function name as arguments.

Comment: @KahnYe then just don't have a `try-catch`.

Comment: Thank you all for the help and suggestions.  I think I can consider my question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add some trace information to any passing exception you <sup>1</sup>can do this:

```
auto func_A()
    -> double
{
    try
    {
        // The complete original function body.

        double const a = 2*some_func();
        return a/2;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        throw_with_nested( runtime_error( __func__ ) );
    }
}
```

But repeating that everywhere could be a bit tedious and error prone, so you might want to centralize the logic and instead express the function as e.g.

```
auto func_A()
    -> double
{
    return with_trace( __func__, [&]() -> double
    {
        // The complete original function body.

        double const a = 2*some_func();
        return a/2;
    } );
}
```

Now this requires a bit of support machinery both down-call and up-call, e.g.

```
#include <exception>    // std::throw_with_nested
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>    // std::runtime_error, std::exception
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <vector>       // std::vector

namespace cppx {
    using std::runtime_error;
    using std::throw_with_nested;

    template< class Func >
    auto with_trace( char const* const func_name, Func const body )
        -> decltype( body() )
    {
        try
        {
            return body();
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            throw_with_nested( runtime_error( func_name ) );
        }
    }

    namespace x_io
    {
        using std::endl;
        using std::exception;
        using std::cerr;            // For client code.
        using std::ostream;
        using std::rethrow_if_nested;

        namespace impl {
            void print_on( ostream& stream, exception const& x, bool const is_nested )
            {
                stream << (is_nested? ">" : "!") << x.what() << endl;
                try
                {
                    rethrow_if_nested( x );
                }
                catch( exception const& nested_x )
                {
                    print_on( stream, nested_x, true );
                }
                catch( ... )
                {
                    stream << "<unknown exception type>" << endl;
                }
            }
        }  // namespace impl

        auto operator<<( ostream& stream, exception const& x )
            -> ostream&
        {
            impl::print_on( stream, x, false );
            return stream;
        }
    }    // namespace x_io
}  // namespace cppx

namespace my {
    using std::runtime_error;
    using std::string;
    using std::vector;
    using cppx::with_trace;

    bool fail_is_good;

    auto some_func()
        -> double
    {
        if( fail_is_good ) { throw runtime_error( "some_func" ); }
        return 3.14;
    }

    auto func_A()
        -> double
    {
        return with_trace( __func__, [&]() -> double
        {
            double const a = 2*some_func();
            return a/2;
        } );
    }

    void cpp_main( vector< string > const& args )
    {
        using std::cout; using std::endl;
        my::fail_is_good = (args.size() > 1);
        cout << func_A() << endl;
    }
}  // namespace my

auto main( int argc, char* argv[] )
    -> int
{
    using std::exception; using std::string; using std::vector;
    try
    {
        my::cpp_main( vector<string>( argv, argv + argc ) );
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        using namespace cppx::x_io;
        cerr << x << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) Unfortunately Visual C++ 12.0 (2013), even in its November 2013 CTP incarnation, doesn't support `std::throw_with_nested`. Such support can easily be added by just implementing it. Also, as I recall it doesn't support `__func__`, but that macro is also easy to define.</sup>